# Visual Studio 2017 detect memory Leak when using Poco Xml Document

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, poco-libraries

If i use the `Poco::XML::Document` Class, Visual Studio dumps a Memory Leak after the Application runs.

I created a simple `ConsoleApplication` from Visual Studio 2017 Project Templates and added the following Code to the `Main`

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>  
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/DOM/Document.h>
#include <Poco/DOM/AutoPtr.h>
int main()
{
    Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> pDoc = new Poco::XML::Document;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Leak Dump inside Visual Studio (i omitted some Parts because it's really large):

```
{1976} normal block at 0x0130C048, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <, /     > 2C 18 2F 01 00 00 00 00 
{1975} normal block at 0x0130C0F0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  /     > 10 18 2F 01 00 00 00 00 
{1974} normal block at 0x0130BD70, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  /     > F4 17 2F 01 00 00 00 00 
{1973} normal block at 0x0130BE88, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  /     > D4 17 2F 01 00 00 00 00 

....

{174} normal block at 0x012D87E0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > C4 0B 89 0F 00 00 00 00 
{173} normal block at 0x012DB928, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%> 25 59 2D 25 6D 2D 25 64 54 25 48 3A 25 4D 3A 25 
{172} normal block at 0x012D87A8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <d       > 64 0E 89 0F 00 00 00 00 
{171} normal block at 0x012D8AF0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <L       > 4C 0B 89 0F 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

I use Poco as a DLL.
The Version of Poco is 1.9.0
I also used Dr. Memory to detected Memory Leaks. This is the summary of the Leak Run:

```
ERRORS FOUND:
              12 unique,    12 total unaddressable access(es)
               0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
             146 unique,   201 total invalid heap argument(s)
               0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
               0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
               0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
               0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
               0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2438#issuecomment-416562449).

Here's the proper way to check for leaks:

```
int main()
{
    _CrtMemState _state[3] = {0};
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&_state[0]);
    {
        Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> pDoc = new Poco::XML::Document;
    }
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&_state[1]);
    if (_CrtMemDifference(&_state[2], &_state[0], &_state[1]))
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&_state[2]); // Dump Memory Leaks
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for showing me this. And you are right if i write it like this everythings ok =) it helped me alot to find the leaks in my Class which uses the `Poco::XML` .

Answer (score 3):

The first noticeable thing is that `pDoc` is still alive when you call for leak reports. So you should 1) reduce scope of `pDoc` 2) stop using iostream to avoid possible creation of guards and check again.

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>  
#include <Poco/DOM/Document.h>
#include <Poco/DOM/AutoPtr.h>
int main()
{
    {
        Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> pDoc = new Poco::XML::Document;
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Also it would be better to use VS memory profiler rather than `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the scope but the output is still the same. It Dumps out the Memory Leak

Comment: @Kevin "memory leaks" are perfectly normal in c++ code, many libraries will statically allocate memory which is only freed when the application terminates. Things to look out for is if you run your code twice do you get more memory leaks reported? These will be genuine leaks rather than static allocations.

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, memory leaks are errors, not "perfectly normal". Statically allocated memory is a different beast, it may make memory leaks analysis more complex, but they are not, strictly speaking "memory leaks" (because, if done correctly, no memory is "leaked")

Comment: @roalz I meant some "memory leaks" (as reported by simple tools such as `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`) are perfectly normal. The rest of my comment explains how to find real memory leaks with these tools

Comment: @AlanBirtles If you meant "you may expect some false positives reported as memory leaks by brain-dead tools like _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks", then I agree ;-)